# Listen to Firestore Metadata changes with Angular Fire

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, progressive-web-apps, offlineapps

Per the Firebase docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen, one can add {includeMetadataChanges: true} as an option to the .onSnapshot() method. How can I do this with angular/fire/firestore so that my app can know when data has been shipped up to the server in my offline capable PWA? Here's what I have so far, which obviously doesn't work:

```
this.afs.collection(`collection`).snapshotChanges({includeMetadataChanges: true}).pipe(
  map(arr => {
    return arr.map(snap => {
      const id = snap.payload.doc.id;
      const data = snap.payload.doc.data() as Entry;
      const fromCache = snap.payload.doc.metadata.fromCache;
      const hasPendingWrites = snap.payload.doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites;
      return { fromCache, hasPendingWrites, id, ...data };
    });
  })
)
```

Comment: I don't have time to deep dive into this, but from glancing at the [AngularFire2 docs for Firestore](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges), for `.snapshotChanges()`, it includes the sentence "_Why would you use it? - When you need a list of data but also want to keep around metadata._"

Comment: ...which leads me to think it already includes the metadata you're looking for... unless it doesn't *listen* to the metadata and only returns it - in which case, without a deep dive, I could only recommend skipping the AF2 implementation here and relying on the original base Firebase package for this feature.

Comment: That's correct @JeremyW, .snapshotChanges() pulls down the metadata but doesn't _listen_ to it which is what I'm looking for. I had thought that I might have to resort to relying on the base Firebase package for this but haven't actually used it yet, so I've got to learn that little bit now, but it shouldn't be too hard. (unless someone else has as easier solution)